# how to make input based on number of elements in array react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

There is a list of question saved in the state of listQuestion. Each question will have an answer input field. How to store the inputted value and how to use onChangetext to save the value for each question?

```
state = {
    listQuestion: [],
  };
async componentDidMount() {
   let question = await AsyncStorage.getItem("QuestionUser");
   if (question) {
      this.setState({ listQuestion: JSON.parse(question) });
    }
 }
renderTableData() {
    return this.state.listQuestion.map(ques => {
      const { question } = ques;
      return (
        <View style={styles.headerBottom}>
          <View style={styles.nameView}>
            <Text style={styles.textName}>{question} </Text> // display question
            <Input></Input> // how to use value and onChangeText for each question
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: It is a bit different to that one. Have a look at it properly

Answer (score 0):

const quesIndex = listQuestion.findIndex((ques)=>ques=={target.value});
listQuestion[quesIndex] = {target.value};

Comment: Why are you trying to find the index of question?
There are 5 questions in listQuestion. There should be 5 answers so the goal is to add answer to each question.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to render all the input based on your listQuestion inside your render return. I am assuming in listQuestion array for every question it will have unique id for each question on which basis we will detect which value is being change.

```
{
 listQuestion.map((item, index) => {
   return (
       <Input value = {item.value} onChange = {(e) => {this.handleOnChange(e, 
 item.id)} }></Input>
   );
 });
}
// item.id <= it is the unique identifier for each question object.
```

now you need to create a function which will handle onChange

```
handleOnChange(e, id) {
 const {listQuestion} = this.state;
 listQuestion.forEach((item, index) => {
   (item.id == id) {
     item.value = e.target.value;
   }
 })
 this.setState({listQuestion})
}
```

also inside your constructor

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
  listQuestion: []
 }
 this.handleOnChange = this.handleOnChange.bind(this);
}
```

let's say you have no unique id then you can rely on the index so you can change this...

```
<Input value = {item.value} onChange = {(e) => {this.handleOnChange(e, 
 index)} }></Input>
// it will send the index along with event, hence we can change value in listQuestion on the basis of index.
```

and just change this in onChange function

```
handleOnChange(e, questionIndex) {
 const {listQuestion} = this.state;
 listQuestion.forEach((item, index) => {
   (questionIndex == id) {
     item.value = e.target.value;
   }
 })
 this.setState({listQuestion})
}

// hence it will find the index in listQuestion array and change value of that particular index.
```

Comment: you just need to be sure how you can provide value and onChange function to your <Input /> becuase this works on <input type  = "text"/> things, and you are using ui framework or library i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Added a newstate to hold the answers in the form:

```
listAnswers = {
 question1: value,
 ...
};
```

Make a custom component for text input, so that we can give additional props.

```
state = {
 listQuestion: [],
  listAnswers: {},
};
handleInput = (name, value) => {
 this.setState({listAnswers[name]: value }); 
}

renderTableData() {
 return this.state.listQuestion.map(ques => {
  const { question } = ques;
  return (
    <View style={styles.headerBottom}>
      <View style={styles.nameView}>
        <TextInput style={styles.textName}>{question} </Text> // display question
        <Input name={question} value={this.state.listanswers[question] || ''} onPress={this.handleInput}></Input>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
 });
}
```

### TextInput Component

```
const TextInputComponent = ({value, onChangeText, name, ...props}) => (
 <Input
    value={value}
    onChangeText={(value) => onPress(name, value)} //... Bind the name here
    {...props}
 />
);
```